# Visualizing weighted directed graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a weighted, directed graph with 100 vertices and the maximal number of edges, 9900.  Are there *Mathematica* tools or packages available to visualize which edges have large weights?  (If you know of non-*Mathematica* software, that's fine, too.)

Background:  My institution has 100 majors, and I'm interested in studying how students change majors, where they start compared to where they end up.

Comment: What do you mean by "the maximal number of edges, 20,000"?  A 100-vertex (simple) directed graph won't have more than 9900 edges.  I am not sure how to draw this many edges and still show some useful information about individual ones ...

Comment: @Szabolcs  OK  9900 in each direction, omitting loops, gives 19800.  The large number is precisely the question - I'm looking for a visualization to emphasize the largest weights.

Comment: If there's an edge in each direction, that would give 9900 total, not 19800.  Why don't you just drop the low-weight edges (threshold the weighted adjacency matrix) and adjust the thickness/opacity of the remaining ones according to their weights?

Comment: @Szabolcs  Of course you're right; I'll edit the question.  And thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try that, but am interested if there's a better approach.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider statistical validation of the edges, which is another, a tad more involved method of pruning away the less important edges, see for example [here](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0017994). Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with the details so I won't be able to help you further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will use [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) for the following answer.

Here's a complete directed graph on 100 with weighted edges. There are lots of edges with small weights and a few with large weights.

```
graph = CompleteGraph[100, DirectedEdges -> True, 
   EdgeWeight -> RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[5], 100 99]];
```

We will:

- remove edges below a certain weight threshold
- style the remaining edges based on weight by adjusting their opacity and thickness

First, I need to utility functions.

Threshold an array (replace values below the threshold by zero). [`Threshold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threshold.html) does not seem to work on sparse arrays.

```
threshold[arr_, th_] := arr UnitStep[arr - th]
```

Scale the elements of an array so that the largest is 1.

```
scale[arr_] := arr/Max@Abs[arr]
```

Now we convert the graph to a weighted adjacency matrix, threshold, convert back, then style it.

```
IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[
   VertexList[graph], 
   threshold[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph], 0.9], 
   GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", ImageSize -> Large
] //
IGEdgeMap[
  Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5 #], Opacity[#], Arrowheads[0.05 #]] &,
  EdgeStyle -> scale@*IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]
]
```

[image]

We could use a smaller threshold to include more edges, but compute the opacity based on a power of the weight, to emphasize strong edges and fade out weak ones.

```
IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[VertexList[graph], 
  threshold[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[graph], 0.7], 
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", ImageSize -> Large] //     
 IGEdgeMap[
  Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5 #], Opacity[#^3], 
    Arrowheads[0.05 #]] &, EdgeStyle -> scale@*IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]]
```

[image]

These choices about visualization are yours to make.

Answer (score 0):

To draw the subgraph with large weights, you might want to apply the following function:

```
select[matrix_, lB_, uB_] := 
  matrix*Map[Boole[lB <= # <= uB] &, matrix, {-1}];
sa = SparseArray[select[mat, .1, .6]];
weightedG = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], DirectedEdges -> True];
GraphPlot[weightedG]
```

You can apply the `select[...]` function for various domains `{lB, uB}` on matrix `mat` and draw the directed graph only for the desired domain.